# How does a webserver handle a connection lost?

Tags: web-server, http, https, networking

How does a web server handle a lost connection, for example the client sends a request and due to some problem got disconnected from the server before the latter could reply with a response, what does a typical web server do in these kind of scenarios

Comment: It would be helpful to answer the question @Vamsi didn't realize he was asking. It would help others who discover this post as well.  A search on "http is stateless" will explain what's going on.  There are even discussions here and on Stackoverflow about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers make requests. Web servers reply to requests. They neither know nor care what happens once that reply has been sent. Think of it like the UDP protocol.

Comment: I'm asking what happens when the browser that made the request is no longer available to listen to that request, will the server still reply ?

Comment: @Vamsi, I really thought I was clear on that. When a web server receives a request from a browser it sends a response. That's all that happens. The web server cannot even know if that browser is still listening or not, let alone care about it. There are some application methods used to maintain a psuedo connection but the web server is not directly involved in that. It listens and it replies. It does nothing else. It's like light leaving a torch/flashlight. It goes out but the source knows nothing about it from that point onwards.

Comment: "The web server cannot even know if that browser is still listening or not, let alone care about it." - it does know and care about it, and will terminate that connection (= won't try to send more and it will free resources, etc).

Comment: @yi_H, I think you're confusing the web server level with the application level.

Comment: @John Gardeniers: let's assume I'm requesting a 1G file download from the webserver, and then I disconnect.. what do you think will happen?

Comment: Why don't you run it through Wireshark and see for yourself. You're clearly not going to accept anything I say.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't do anything. What's it supposed to do? The connection is gone.

Comment: I mean will it still reply ?

Comment: If the TCP connection is gone, how is it going to reply?